POST http://localhost:3000/protected net::ERR_ABORTED 500 (Internal Server Error) when uploading PDF
I'm getting a  500 error when I attempt to upload the file.
POST http://localhost:3000/protected net::ERR_ABORTED 500 (Internal Server Error)
Here is my code:
FileUpload.tsx:
'use client';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { InboxOutlined, UploadOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';
import { message, Upload, Form, Space, Button } from 'antd';

const { Dragger } = Upload;

const formItemLayout = {
    labelCol: { span: 6 },
    wrapperCol: { span: 14 },
};

const normFile = (e: any) => {
    console.log('Upload event:', e);
    if (Array.isArray(e)) {
        return e;
    }
    return e?.fileList;
};

const onFinish = (values: any) => {
    console.log('Received values of form: ', values);
};

const InputFile = ({ uploadFile }: { uploadFile: (file: any) => Promise<void> }) => {
    const [fileList, setFileList] = useState<any[]>([]);
    const handleUpload = async () => {
        await uploadFile(fileList[0]);
    };

    return (
        <Form
            name='validate_other'
            {...formItemLayout}
            onFinish={onFinish}
            initialValues={{
                'input-number': 3,
                'checkbox-group': ['A', 'B'],
                'rate': 3.5,
                'color-picker': null,
            }}
            style={{ maxWidth: 600 }}>
            <Form.Item name='dragger' valuePropName='fileList' getValueFromEvent={normFile} noStyle>
                <Dragger
                    type='drag'
                    name='files'
                    // pdf only
                    accept='.pdf'
                    beforeUpload={(file) => {
                        const isPdf = file.type === 'application/pdf';
                        if (!isPdf) {
                            message.error('You can only upload PDF file!');
                        }
                        setFileList((prev) => [...prev, file]);
                        return false;
                    }}
                    onChange={(info) => {
                        const { status } = info.file;
                        if (status !== 'uploading') {
                            console.log(info.file, info.fileList);
                        }
                        if (status === 'done') {
                            message.success(`${info.file.name} file uploaded successfully.`);
                        } else if (status === 'error') {
                            message.error(`${info.file.name} file upload failed.`);
                        }
                    }}>
                    <p className='ant-upload-drag-icon'>
                        <InboxOutlined />
                    </p>
                    <p className='ant-upload-text'>Click or drag file to this area to upload</p>
                    <p className='ant-upload-hint'>
                        Support for a single or bulk upload. Strictly prohibited from uploading company data or other banned
                        files.
                    </p>
                </Dragger>
            </Form.Item>

            <Form.Item wrapperCol={{ span: 12, offset: 6 }}>
                <Space>
                    <Button type='primary' htmlType='submit' onClick={() => handleUpload()}>
                        Submit
                    </Button>
                    <Button htmlType='reset'>reset</Button>
                </Space>
            </Form.Item>
        </Form>
    );
};

export default InputFile;

/protected/page.tsx
import DeployButton from '../../components/DeployButton';
import AuthButton from '../../components/AuthButton';
import { createClient } from '../../utils/supabase/server';
import { redirect } from 'next/navigation';
import React from 'react';
import InputFile from '../../components/FileUpload';

export default async function ProtectedPage() {
    const supabase = createClient();

    const {
        data: { user },
    } = await supabase.auth.getUser();

    if (!user) {
        return redirect('/login');
    }
    const uploadFile = async (file: any) => {
        'use server';

        const { data, error } = await supabase.storage.from('fax-data').upload('test.pdf', file);
        if (error) {
            console.error('Error uploading file: ', error.message);
            return;
        }
        console.log('File uploaded: ', data);
    };

    return (
        <div className='flex-1 w-full flex flex-col gap-20 items-center'>
            <div className='w-full'>
                <div className='py-6 font-bold bg-purple-950 text-center'>
                    This is a protected page that you can only see as an authenticated user
                </div>
                <nav className='w-full flex justify-center border-b border-b-foreground/10 h-16'>
                    <div className='w-full max-w-4xl flex justify-between items-center p-3 text-sm'>
                        <DeployButton />
                        <AuthButton />
                    </div>
                </nav>
                <InputFile uploadFile={uploadFile} />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

I'm not sure what exactly is going on since I think I passed all the 'use client' and 'use server' phrases correctly.

Investigate server logs to identify the cause of the internal server error. Your client side code cannot give even the slightest hint so you are better off using your time more appropriately by looking at the right place.
